# Using concatMap to run a Single before running another observable

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, concatmap

```
Android Studio 3.1 RC 2
kotlin 1.2.30
```

The signature of the fetchMessage in Java

```
Single<Response> fetchMessage(final String Id);
```

The kotlin code

```
fun translate(Id: String): Completable {
        return repository.fetchMessage(Id)
                .flatMap {
                    Single.fromCallable<State>({
                        update(messageId, it, State.COMPLETED)
                        State.COMPLETED
                    })
                }
                .onErrorReturn({
                    update(Id, null, State.ERROR)
                    State.ERROR
                })
                .toCompletable()
    }
```

The method I want to run before fetchMessage

```
 fun insertMessage(Id: String): Completable {
        return Completable.fromCallable {
            insert(Id, State.IDLE)
        }
    }
```

I want the insertMessage e to somehow run before the fetchMessage. I was thinking of using concatMap but not sure how to combine the translate and insertMessage. So that the insertMessage will run first then once completed the translate will run.

Many thanks for any suggestions,

```
Update solution 1 using startWith(..):
```

By changing the return to Single for the translate method. I have done like this:

```
fun translate(Id: String): Single<State> {
        return repository.fetchMessage(Id)
                .flatMap {
                    Single.fromCallable<State>({
                        update(messageId, it, State.COMPLETED)
                        State.COMPLETED
                    })
                }
                .onErrorReturn({
                    update(Id, null, State.ERROR)
                    State.ERROR
                })
    }
```

Then I can have a method to do the following insertMessage(..) -> translate(..):

```
translate(Id).toCompletable().startWith(insertMessage(id, State.IDLE))
```

Would that be an ideal solution?

```
Update solution 2 using concatWith(..):
```

My returning a Observable and calling toObservable() in the chain.

```
fun translate(Id: String): Observable<State> {
        return repository.fetchMessage(Id)
                .flatMap {
                    Single.fromCallable<State>({
                        update(messageId, it, State.COMPLETED)
                        State.COMPLETED
                    })
                }
                .onErrorReturn({
                    update(Id, null, State.ERROR)
                    State.ERROR
                })
                .toObservable()
    }
```

And I can use concatWith so the sequence would be insertMessage(..) -> translate(..):

```
translate(Id).toCompletable().concatWith(insertMessage(id, State.IDLE).toObservable())
    .toCompletable()
```

Are these correct solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both your options make sense, but I would recommend you to clean them a bit.

First of all you need to clearly understand what return type to use in each case: [Observable](http://reactivex.io/documentation/observable.html), [Single](http://reactivex.io/documentation/single.html) or [Completable](https://static.javadoc.io/io.reactivex/rxjava/1.2.1/rx/Completable.html).

The definition is the following:

- **Single** represent Observable that emit single value or error.
- **Completable** represent Observable that emits no value, but only terminal events, either onError or onCompleted.

In both your cases you don't need any data returned, all you need is to know if the operation is successful or not. Completable is designed to handle exactly this case.

So I'd recommend you to have:

```
fun translate(Id: String): Completable {
    return repository.fetchMessage(Id)
             .flatMapCompletable {
                Completable.fromAction {
                  update(messageId, it, State.COMPLETED)
                }
             }.doOnError {
                update(Id, null, State.ERROR)
             }
}

fun insertMessage(Id: String): Completable {
    return Completable.fromCallable {
        insert(Id, State.IDLE)
    }
}
```

Nice option to make your code cleaner is to use [Completable.fromAction](https://static.javadoc.io/io.reactivex/rxjava/1.2.1/rx/Completable.html#fromAction(rx.functions.Action0)) instead of [Completable.fromCallable](https://static.javadoc.io/io.reactivex/rxjava/1.2.1/rx/Completable.html#fromCallable(java.util.concurrent.Callable)), so you don't need to return anything.

Then you can use any of your options, [startWith](https://static.javadoc.io/io.reactivex/rxjava/1.2.1/rx/Completable.html#startWith(rx.Completable)) or [concatWith](https://static.javadoc.io/io.reactivex/rxjava/1.2.1/rx/Completable.html#concatWith(rx.Completable)). Both wait until first observable completes before running the second observable. I prefer to use concatWith, because it runs the functions in the same order that they are written.

Eventually we get an elegant solution:

```
insertMessage(id).concatWith(translate(id))
```

or

```
translate(id).startWith(insertMessage(id))
```

More info about concat: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/concat.html

Here is the implementation of the functions inside the rxJava library if you are curious:

```
public final Completable startWith(Completable other) {
    requireNonNull(other);
    return concat(other, this);
}

public final Completable concatWith(Completable other) {
    requireNonNull(other);
    return concat(this, other);
}
```

As you can see the only difference is the order.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a `Completable`, you can chain any other reactive type with it via [`andThen`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Completable.html#andThen-io.reactivex.CompletableSource-):

```
insertMessage("id")
.andThen(translate("id"))
```

Comment: thanks for your answer and pointed me in the right direction. I have updated my answer with 2 possible answers. However, I couldn't get concatMap to work.

Comment: There is no `concatMap` for `Single`s and `Completable`s.

Comment: Thanks, however, what do you think of my updated answers?

Comment: Try them out yourself and if they don't work, post a new question detailing what's wrong. We usually don't have the context to run it for you nor have the capacity to do so. There is the [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site to ask for reviews.